# Retrieving value of input box with keyup - JS

Tags: javascript

In my code below, this is what i am trying to achieve. I have two input boxes, quantity and price. None of them are fixed, meaning clients/users can input any figure they want and the code must multiply to give the total.

Below with my code, quantity box seems to be working fine but i am not able to get the values of my price value in the price box. I get the total to be NAN.

What am i not doing right in my code and why is the keyup not working for my price input box?

PS: Beginner in javascript and pardon for my english

```
<div class="checkout_panel">
<div class="panel_checkout">
</div>

</div>

  '<div class="order_container" style=" font-size:14px; "> '+ 

    '<td  class="qtyhtml" ><input  type="text" style="width:55px;text-align:left;"  value="1" class="form-control quantity" id="qty" placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]"  required/></td>'+
    '<td  class="price" ><input  type="text"  style="width:55px;text-align:left;"  value="'+ad.retail_price+'" class="form-control price" id="price" placeholder=" qty " name="price[]"  required/></td>'+


    '<td><p class="total" >GHS<span class="line-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p></td>'+
       '</tr>'+
    '</tbody>'+
    '</table>'+
    '</div>'

    $('.checkout_panel').on('keyup','.quantity',function()

           {

           order_container = $(this).closest('div');

           quantity = Number($(this).val());
           price =  
           Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').val());

           order_container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);

            sum = 0;

           $(".line-total").each(function(){
           sum = sum + Number($(this).text());

           })   





        });
```

Comment: If you made your html a bit less messy and gave your inputs meaningful classes and not both your td and input sharing the same `price` class, and not write brittle code like .close('div') or '.price span' it would probably be clearer to you ;) Also you could make it easier for people to help if you removed all the quotes around the html and made a runnable example - first step console.log and ensure you are getting the correct element, next step log the result of .val() on it and see what it says

Answer (score 1):

`.find('.price')` will find `<td class="price">` but it's `<input class="form-control price">` that has the value you want. Change `'.price'` to something which selects the input specifically, like `'.form-control.price'` or `'input.price'`.